# How can i use a dump-file saved with HttpRequest.SaveAs to re-send the request to my localhost?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http, fiddler

I'm troubleshooting an integration between an external service which posts multipart/form-data data to a Controller in MVC3.

On the production server I've captured erroneous request using [HttpRequest.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.saveas.aspx) to a file.

Is there any tool I can use to "replay" the request on my localhost so I can debug with Visual Studio?

(I've been trying with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) but I can't get it working right. If a dump a local request from a simple form with POST my controller recieves the files correctly. If i dump the same request and copy paste it into fiddler as raw and send the files are missing so there's something wrong.)

Since there's a built-in function to dump the request I'm thinking it might be some official way to resend the request as well. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working in fiddler if I do exactly this in the composer:

1. Open the dumpfile in notepad
2. Choose Parsed
3. Only enter  the Content-Type as headers (and let fiddler add the others even if they were the same)
4. Paste the body of the request in request body from notepad

> POST: http://`localhost`/Controller/Action

**Request headers:**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=fJP-UWKXo6xvqX7niGR0StXXFQwdKhHc9quF
```

**Request body:**

```
--fJP-UWKXo6xvqX7niGR0StXXFQwdKhHc9quF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mmsimage"; filename="IMG_0959.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=IMG_0959.jpg; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<the encoded file goes here as jibberish>

--fJP-UWKXo6xvqX7niGR0StXXFQwdKhHc9quF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somefield"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

value of somefield
--fJP-UWKXo6xvqX7niGR0StXXFQwdKhHc9quF--
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used NCAT command line tool to replay requests captured by SaveAs method.
Command looks like this:

```
NCAT localhost 80 < CapFileName
```

you can find it in [NMAP library](http://nmap.org/download.html)

[See my blog](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2013/01/20/C-code-to-play-PCAP-capture-of-HTTP-request.aspx) for more information.